# Migrating a Rails 2 app to Rails 3: `image_path` throws "undefined local variable or method 'config'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2, actionview, active-form

### background

I am trying to migrate an old Rails 2 (Ruby 1.8.7) app to Rails 3.0.9 (Ruby 1.9.3) — yes it's a stepping stone to get it to Rails 4 and Ruby 2.2 — and I've hit the following problem.

The original app makes extensive use of [an old `Active Form` gem](http://activeform.rubyforge.org) which we've [hacked slightly to support Ruby 1.9](https://github.com/davesag/active_form/tree/replace_parsedate).

It mostly works, but there appears to be some issue with how it interacts with the `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` that's part of `ActionPack 3.0.9`.

In my specific case I have an `ActiveForm::DateCalendarSection` (built dynamically) which subclasses [`ActiveForm::Element::Section`](https://github.com/davesag/active_form/blob/replace_parsedate/lib/active_form/elements/section.rb), which, according to `self.class.ancestors`, is a subclass of [`ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper). Looking at the `ActiveForm` source however there is no mention of `AssetTagHelper` or `asset_tag_helper` so how they are actually connected remains a mystery to me.

### Problem

Calls to the method `image_path` result in an error

```
undefined local variable or method 'config'
```

The call to `image_path` is simply a wrapper around a call to [`compute_public_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/compute_public_path) in `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb, line 741
def compute_public_path(source, dir, ext = nil, include_host = true)
  return source if is_uri?(source)

  source += ".#{ext}" if rewrite_extension?(source, dir, ext)
  source  = "/#{dir}/#{source}" unless source[0] == //
  source = rewrite_asset_path(source, config.asset_path)

  has_request = controller.respond_to?(:request)
  if has_request && include_host && source !~ %{^#{controller.config.relative_url_root}/}
    source = "#{controller.config.relative_url_root}#{source}"
  end
  source = rewrite_host_and_protocol(source, has_request) if include_host

  source
end
```

Diving into that with `binding.pry` it's evident that `config` is indeed not defined. Likewise `controller` is also not defined.

## Question

What would have changed between Rails 2 and Rails 3, such that methods from `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` can no longer access Rails' `config` or the current `controller`?

Answer (score 0):

It could be you don't have enough of the Rails support loaded. Maybe pull in everything inside your gem with

```
require "active_support/all"
```

Alternatively, have a look at how modern Rails hooks things up via a proxy to the config:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12622/files